# Heroku上でのエラー"AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'"

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, flask

Herokuでフラスコアプリケーションをデプロイしようとしているのですが、
動作時にエラーが発生してしまいます。
アプリは、画像をOpenCVによって分析するものですが、その際にエラーが発生します。

heroku logでエラーを確認すると

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

と表示されています。
ローカル環境では、問題なく動作するので、
openCVをHerokuに正しく導入できていないと思ったので、以下のコードをheroku.ymlに追加しpushしました。

```
build:
  languages:
    - python
  packages:
    - libopencv-dev
run:
  web: gunicorn server:app --log-file -
```

これでも、同じエラーが発生してしまいます...
opencv_contrib_pythonやopencv-pythonを再インストールしても状況は変わりません。
今の所、Herokuでopencv_contrib_pythonをインポートする必要があると考えているのですが
どのようにすべきかわかりません。

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

以下、こちらが実際のコードになります。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

```
def load_model():
    global recognizer
    print(" * Loading pre-trained model ...")
    cascadePath = './haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath)
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Comment: 英語で投稿してしまいましたが、日本語で投稿し直しました。初投稿でよくわかっておらず恐縮なのですが、再度"オープン”とさせていただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 本家への質問 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205457/

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Heroku、FlaskとOpenCVの環境構築](https://qiita.com/maeda_mikio/items/1a6899e104aac7b138fc), [herokuでOpenCVを利用する Python3](https://qiita.com/haru1843/items/210cb08024195b9d1bc8), [How to use OpenCV with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49469764/9014308), [herokuで python3 + opencv を動かす 2018/09/16](https://kaeru-nantoka.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/09/16/225004)

Comment: 対応およびコメント頂き誠にありがとうございます！お知らせ頂いたサイトを参考に、heroku-buildpack-apt、Aptfileを追加してみましたが、同じエラーが出てる状態です。。。仮想環境構築にAnacondaを使用しており、明るくないのですが、Docker等環境構築の技術を勉強する必要を感じております!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herokuで当てはまるかどうか分かりませんが、以下のいくつかの記事を見ると、

`opencv-python`と`opencv-contrib-python`の両方をインストールしてはいけない。
どちらか片方のみをインストールすること、そして`face`を使うなら`opencv-contrib-python`らしいです。

ただし未承認ですが、逆に両方インストールで解決したという回答もあります。

[AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'faces' in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55581161/9014308)
承認マーク付き回答

> Try update OpenCV with
>
> ```
> pip install opencv-contrib-python
> ```

それに付いたコメント

> It worked in my case. Do you know how are these modules: opencv-contrib-python and openCV different?
>
> 私の場合はうまくいきました。これらのモジュール：opencv-contrib-pythonとopenCVがどのように異なるか知っていますか？
>
> I believe`opencv-contrib-python`is the unofficial pre-built OpenCV package. It's not the official OpenCV package released by OpenCV.org. There is also`opencv-python`which contains just the main modules of the OpenCV library while`opencv-contrib-python`contains both the main modules along with the contrib modules. You don't want to install both, pick only one.
>
> opencv-contrib-pythonは、非公式のビルド済みOpenCVパッケージだと思います。
>   OpenCV.orgによってリリースされた公式のOpenCVパッケージではありません。
>   また、OpenCVライブラリのメインモジュールのみを含むopencv-pythonがあり、opencv-contrib-pythonにはcontribモジュールとともにメインモジュールの両方が含まれます。
>   両方をインストールするのではなく、1つだけを選択します。

本家で同様のものが解決済みらしいです。
[module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face' #13848 - opencv/opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13848)

他に承認マークは無いですが、類似の回答もあります。
[module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54158806/9014308)

> The`face`module isn't actually a part of the`opencv`library proper. Rather, [face is part](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face) of the`opencv-contrib`library. From the readme:
>
> > This repository [`opencv-contrib`] is intended for development of so-called "extra" modules, contributed functionality. New modules quite often do not have stable API, and they are not well-tested. Thus, they shouldn't be released as a part of official OpenCV distribution, since the library maintains binary compatibility, and tries to provide decent performance and stability.
>
> `opencv-contrib`needs to be installed separately. As @james pointed out (in a now deleted comment), the current easy way to get the Python version is to just do:
>
> ```
> pip install opencv-contrib-python
> ```
>
> After you run the above`pip`call, your code should work.

逆にこちらは未承認ですが両方インストールして動作したらしいです。
[AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51274439/9014308)

> Finally, I got it working. I just used pip for both installations:
>
> ```
> pip install opencv-python
> pip install opencv-contrib-python
> ```

類似で未承認。
[AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44633378/9014308)
[attributeerror: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'createlbphfacerecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45655699/9014308)

Comment: " pip uninstall opencv-python","pip freeze > requirements.txt","git push heroku master"を行なった結果、heroku上でも動きました！！ご指摘の通り、opencv-contrib-pythonとopenCVが競合していたようです。有難うございました！